# android: Animate color change from color to color

Tags: android, colors

Assuming I have two colors, and I need to create a real time animation that fastly switches from a color to another.

I tried just to increment the color hexadecimal until I reach the other, but that gave a really bad animation as it showed lots of unrelated colors.

I am using `setColorFilter(color, colorfilter)` to change the color of an imageview.

Changing the HUE will give me the best visual results? If so, how can I change it for a solid color?

SOLUTION:
I solved it by recursively shifting hue

```
private int hueChange(int c,int deg){
       float[] hsv = new float[3];       //array to store HSV values
       Color.colorToHSV(c,hsv); //get original HSV values of pixel
       hsv[0]=hsv[0]+deg;                //add the shift to the HUE of HSV array
       hsv[0]=hsv[0]%360;                //confines hue to values:[0,360]
       return Color.HSVToColor(Color.alpha(c),hsv);
    }
```

Comment: did you try TransitionDrawable?

Comment: Color of what? Background of an ImageView?

Comment: Color of the colorfilter of an imageview.
No I didn't use TransitionDrawable because the drawable isn't fixed neither are the colors.

Comment: what do you mean: deawable isnt fixed?

Comment: To use offset to blend colors see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24285364/400493

Comment: you can refer this answer for color animation http://stackoverflow.com/a/34429554/2149195

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLUTION: I solved it by recursively shifting hue

```
private int hueChange(int c,int deg){
       float[] hsv = new float[3];       //array to store HSV values
       Color.colorToHSV(c,hsv); //get original HSV values of pixel
       hsv[0]=hsv[0]+deg;                //add the shift to the HUE of HSV array
       hsv[0]=hsv[0]%360;                //confines hue to values:[0,360]
       return Color.HSVToColor(Color.alpha(c),hsv);
    }
```

Comment: You should use `ValueAnimator` for this type of thing. I've posted an answer on how to do this with HSV values.

Answer (score 77):

Combining @zed's and @Phil's answer gives a nice smooth transition using the `ValueAnimator`.

```
final float[] from = new float[3],
              to =   new float[3];

Color.colorToHSV(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF"), from);   // from white
Color.colorToHSV(Color.parseColor("#FFFF0000"), to);     // to red

ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);   // animate from 0 to 1
anim.setDuration(300);                              // for 300 ms

final float[] hsv  = new float[3];                  // transition color
anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener(){
    @Override public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        // Transition along each axis of HSV (hue, saturation, value)
        hsv[0] = from[0] + (to[0] - from[0])*animation.getAnimatedFraction();
        hsv[1] = from[1] + (to[1] - from[1])*animation.getAnimatedFraction();
        hsv[2] = from[2] + (to[2] - from[2])*animation.getAnimatedFraction();

        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.HSVToColor(hsv));
    }
});

anim.start();
```

---

The HSV will give a nicer transition than Androids default color space because HSV describes colors in cylindrical coordinates that nicely separate the color's properties and allow a smooth transition across a single axis. You can see from the [image below](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) that traveling along the H, S, or V directions gives a nice continuous transition between colors.

[image]

Comment: Hi, in case if you're interested, here is a simple class that I made to make this color interpolation look more natural: https://github.com/konmik/animated-color

Comment: See @dimsuz answer below, it does a lot of this work for you

Comment: This actually looks really bad because for example to animate from blue to dark grey this will pass through green, yellow and even some red.

Comment: Not sure why this is upvoted. The effect of this is quite bad as like @vovahost says it transitions through other colors to get to the target color. For example, if you transition from green to blue, it's green -> cyan -> blue. For Cyan to Magenta, it's cyan -> blue -> magenta. You can get a better effect by just animating the integer color value from source to target as indicated in dimsuz's answer.

Comment: My guess is that I have more upvotes because I answered it a year before the other answer existed ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. I agree, @vovahost's answer is simpler, and probably what most people want. 
However, this answer is good if you need to manually tweak or customize the transition, and the image helps explain how to do that.

Comment: @vovahost the reason why it does that, is because you are not really using the advantage of HSV. If you want to change the saturation, you cannot blend with rgb(100, 100, 100) (gray) since that will most likely translate to hsv(0, 0, 40%) which means it will cycle through the hue. What you instead has to do, is change the saturation from the original color.

Here is an example from green to gray:

green              : rgb(0, 100, 0)          hsv(120, 100%,39.22%)
green step 50 : rgb(50, 100, 50)      hsv(120, 50%, 39.22%)
gray                : rgb(100, 100, 100)  hsv(120, 0%, 39.22%)

Answer (score 67):

You can simply use `ArgbEvaluator` which is available since API 11 (Honeycomb):

```
ValueAnimator anim = new ValueAnimator();
anim.setIntValues(color1, color2);
anim.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
        view.setBackgroundColor((Integer)valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue());
    }
});

anim.setDuration(300);
anim.start();
```

Even better, beginning with API 21 (Lollipop 5.0) you can replace the first 3 lines in the code above with one:

```
ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofArgb(color1, color2)
```

Comment: I find this to work well for these circumstances. Thanks

Comment: This is incredibly useful if you can't depend on API 21 to take advantage of the ofArgb method.  Thanks!

Comment: Strangely enough I experience heavy flickering during the transition, except when I'm using this two colors:  anim.setIntValues(Color.White, Color.yellow). Any ideas?

Comment: @knutella I needed to call `setEvaluator(...)` after `setIntValues(...)` to prevent the flickering.

Comment: @ThomasVos Thanks for your reply. Working now!

Answer (score 20):

You can use a `ValueAnimator`:

```
//animate from your current color to red
ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(view.getBackgroundColor(), Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        view.setBackgroundColor(animation.getAnimatedValue());
    }
});

anim.start();
```

You can also set duration or other parameters before calling `anim.start()`. For example:

```
anim.setDuration(400);
```

will set the animation duration to 400ms.

---

Finally, note that `ValueAnimator` is available starting in *Honeycomb*, so if you are supporting older SDKs, you can use [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com).

Comment: I don't believe it will give me a beautiful visual effect. I managed to do it by shifting hue.

Comment: @ZaidDaba'een from my experience, this does provide a very visually appealing effect, however I am glad you found something else that works well for you.

Comment: @zed will you add your solution as the accepted answer, or accept this one? It would be good to mark this question as answered, since it keeps the site tidy.

Comment: Without ARGB evaluation (as mentioned below) this will just iterate though the color ints, which in most cases will look pretty bad.

Comment: I think you should replace "ofInt()" with "ofArgb()", and "ofArgb()" requires API 21 and above but it works very well for animation that changes color from A to B. "ofInt()" works very bad for me.

Answer (score 14):

best way use blendARGB in ColorUtils.

esay and minimum line code.

```
view.setBackgroundColor(ColorUtils.blendARGB(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"), Color.parseColor("#CCCCCC"), fraction));
```

Comment: very delicate and beautiful solution! Thx!

Answer (score 12):

The other answers gave me a weird effect when transitioning very different colors. From yellow to gray it would reach green at some point during the animation.

What worked best for me was the following snippet. This created a really smooth transition with no weird colors appearing in-between.

```
private void changeViewColor(View view) {
    // Load initial and final colors.
    final int initialColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.some_color);
    final int finalColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.another_color);

    ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
    anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            // Use animation position to blend colors.
            float position = animation.getAnimatedFraction();
            int blended = blendColors(initialColor, finalColor, position);

            // Apply blended color to the view.
            view.setBackgroundColor(blended);
        }
    });

    anim.setDuration(500).start();
}

private int blendColors(int from, int to, float ratio) {
    final float inverseRatio = 1f - ratio;

    final float r = Color.red(to) * ratio + Color.red(from) * inverseRatio;
    final float g = Color.green(to) * ratio + Color.green(from) * inverseRatio;
    final float b = Color.blue(to) * ratio + Color.blue(from) * inverseRatio;

    return Color.rgb((int) r, (int) g, (int) b);
}
```

Comment: Your `blendColors` method seems to be a reimplementation of [ArgbEvaluator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14467625/172690).

Comment: This is works very well. I tried using ArgbEvaluator but for some reason it returned the fraction instead of the arg value.

Answer (score 8):

You can use TransitionDrawable

```
TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) viewObj.getBackground();
transition.startTransition(transitionTime);
```

create xml file in the drawable folder you could write something like:

```
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/end_color" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/start_color" />
</transition>
```

Then, in your xml for the actual View you would reference this TransitionDrawable in the android:background attribute.

Comment: Can you please provide a complete solution here on how to use it in the android:background attribute?

Comment: android:background="@drawable/color_transition"

Comment: @real19 Or programmatically via `view.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(drawableId));`.

Answer (score 5):

The following snippet worked perfectly for me. I thought of using ValueAnimator.ofArgb() but that requires a minimum of api 21. Instead the following works with api 11 and higher. It achieves the color changing smoothly.

```
ArgbEvaluator evaluator = new ArgbEvaluator();
ValueAnimator animator = new ValueAnimator();
animator.setIntValues(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"), Color.parseColor("#000000"));
animator.setEvaluator(evaluator);
animator.setDuration(1000);
//animator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
//animator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            color = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            //postInvalidate(); if you are animating a canvas
            //View.setBackgroundColor(color); another exampleof where to use
        }
    });
animator.start();
```

Answer (score 4):

I've found that the implementation used by `ArgbEvaluator` in the android source code does best job in transitioning colors. When using HSV, depending on the two colors, the transition was jumping through too many hues for me. But this methods doesn't. If you are trying to simply animate use `ArgbEvaluator` with `ValueAnimator` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14467625/2153244):

```
ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo);
colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() { 

    @Override 
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
        view.setBackgroundColor((int) animator.getAnimatedValue());
    } 

}); 
colorAnimation.start();
```

However, if you are like me and want to tie your transition with some user gesture or other value passed from an input, the `ValueAnimator` is not of much help (unless your are targeting for API 22 and above, in which case you can use the [`ValueAnimator.setCurrentFraction()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html#setCurrentFraction(float)) method). When targeting below API 22, wrap the code found in [`ArgbEvaluator` source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/animation/ArgbEvaluator.java) in your own method, as shown below:

```
public static int interpolateColor(float fraction, int startValue, int endValue) {
    int startA = (startValue >> 24) & 0xff;
    int startR = (startValue >> 16) & 0xff;
    int startG = (startValue >> 8) & 0xff;
    int startB = startValue & 0xff;
    int endA = (endValue >> 24) & 0xff;
    int endR = (endValue >> 16) & 0xff;
    int endG = (endValue >> 8) & 0xff;
    int endB = endValue & 0xff;
    return ((startA + (int) (fraction * (endA - startA))) << 24) |
            ((startR + (int) (fraction * (endR - startR))) << 16) |
            ((startG + (int) (fraction * (endG - startG))) << 8) |
            ((startB + (int) (fraction * (endB - startB))));
}
```

and use it however you wish.

Answer (score 4):

If you like me are trying to change from one RGB color to either white or black, you will find it difficult using @bcorso's answer since it's the wrong color space for that particular job. Not that the answer is wrong, that is not what I am saying.

Here is an example of doing the blending using a color `colorA`, using white (which can be substituted with black):

```
float[] from = new float[3];
float[] hsl = new float[3];

ColorUtils.colorToHSL(colorA, from);
float[] to = new float[] {from[0], from[1], 1.0f /* WHITE */};

animator = new ValueAnimator();
animator.setFloatValues(0.0f, 1.0f);
animator.setDuration(1000L);
animator.addUpdateListener(animation -> {
    ColorUtils.blendHSL(from, to, (float) animation.getAnimatedValue(), hsl);

    setColor(ColorUtils.HSLToColor(hsl));
});
```

There seem to be a lot of confusion about the two, so here is a picture describing it visually. 
[image: HSL and HSV]

Answer (score 1):

I tried @bcorso and @damienix and their solution didn't work for me. The math in this function is much simpler as it follows the basic interpolation formula:

p(t) = (1 - t) * p1 + t * p2, where t [0, 1]

```
public int interpolateColorFromTo(int currColor, int nextColor, float t) {
    final float[] from = new float[3];
    final float[] to = new float[3];

    Color.colorToHSV(currColor, from);
    Color.colorToHSV(nextColor, to);

    final float[] hsv  = new float[3];
    hsv[0] = (1.0f - t) * from[0] + t * to[0];
    hsv[1] = (1.0f - t) * from[1] + t * to[1];
    hsv[2] = (1.0f - t) * from[2] + t * to[2];

    return Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would like to thank @bcorso for the great answer and data about HSV.

While I was using the proposed algorithm for some time, I was slightly annoyed by the fact that it makes a color shift from one color to another touching unrelated colors in the process. So, I finally implemented my own stupid simple algorithm that uses real 3D coordinates to make such interpolation:

https://github.com/konmik/animated-color