# How to apply the color animation for a button?

Tags: android

I have a LinearLayout in my xml. When I click on the LinearLayout, I need color appearances for a specific time of onclick event. After that, the color will disappear.

```
holder.ll2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                
                    v.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);
                    v.invalidate();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this 
Make drawable folder in resource file
create this XML
You can change it according to your requirements

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<item android:state_focused="true"
         android:state_pressed="false"
         android:drawable="@drawable/big_box_hover"/>
<item android:state_focused="true"
         android:state_pressed="true"
         android:drawable="@drawable/big_box_hover" /> 
<item android:state_focused="false" 
         android:state_pressed="true" 
         android:drawable="@drawable/big_box_hover" /> 
<item android:drawable="@drawable/big_box" /> 
</selector>
```

Then
in your layout
you can do this

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
            android:background="@drawable/dashboardbuttonclick"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" >
```

Comment: You can set the drawables according to your requirements i.e what kind of color you required when you press the view

Answer (score 0):

You can use Handler for that

```
holder.ll2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) { 
                   handler=new Handler();
                   handler.postDelayed(myRunnable, TIME_MILI_TO_SHOW_COLOR_INT);
                  btn.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);
                }
            }
        });
```

`Runnable` for That

```
 myRunnable=new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                btn.setBackgroundColor(YOUR_DEFAULT_COLOR);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

this link can help you out

[How to create custom button in Android using XML Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507351/how-to-create-custom-button-in-android-using-xml-styles)

Basically you want clicked stated for a button..when clicked it should show a different color and when released show original color.It can be done by defining button stated as xml and then set that xml to button background.

Comment: i want to show the color appearance for when i click on the linearlayout after click event is completed the color is also gone

Comment: when i click a button i need the color effects for background after that it will be disappear

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Button btn = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
//Let's change background's color from blue to red.
ColorDrawable[] color = {new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE), new ColorDrawable(Color.RED)};
TransitionDrawable trans = new TransitionDrawable(color);
//This will work also on old devices. The latest API says you have to use setBackground instead.
btn.setBackgroundDrawable(trans);
trans.startTransition(5000);
```

Comment: How to display the clickevent color effects in android?

Comment: just call this method on button click

Comment: i need color animation for specific time and i am using onclick for layouts

Comment: here 5000 is time...in-between time color change blue to red

Comment: after that my background color will be disappear

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216285/android-animate-color-change-from-color-to-color