# How to create color changing animation? (Android)

Tags: android, animation, colors, textview

I have a `TextView` and some text in it. I need to create an animation with 30 seconds duration, and it will slowly change the color of text from green to red. Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to use a offset rather than animation to blend colors have a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24285364/400493

Comment: ya you can refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34429554/2149195

Answer (score 26, accepted):

1) 30s is a really, really long time, hardly any users would wait to see the end of it.

2) See [Animating with ObjectAnimator](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#object-animator). Something like `ObjectAnimator.ofInt(textView, "textColor", Color.GREEN, Color.RED)` should do what you want. Note, however, that the transition will be linear and will go through a lot of intermediary colors. until it hits `#FF0000`. You can of course specify the points in the middle but in general linear color transitions (in RGB) are not pretty.

Comment: Use anim.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator()) to avoid the blinking.

Answer (score 3):

Delyan's solution works, but as he pointed out, the color transition is not smooth. The following code should give you a smooth color transition:

```
    public static void changeTextColor(final TextView textView, int startColor, int endColor,
                                   final long animDuration, final long animUnit){
    if (textView == null) return;

    final int startRed = Color.red(startColor);
    final int startBlue = Color.blue(startColor);
    final int startGreen = Color.green(startColor);

    final int endRed = Color.red(endColor);
    final int endBlue = Color.blue(endColor);
    final int endGreen = Color.green(endColor);

    new CountDownTimer(animDuration, animUnit){
        //animDuration is the time in ms over which to run the animation
        //animUnit is the time unit in ms, update color after each animUnit

        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {
            int red = (int) (endRed + (l * (startRed - endRed) / animDuration));
            int blue = (int) (endBlue + (l * (startBlue - endBlue) / animDuration));
            int green = (int) (endGreen + (l * (startGreen - endGreen) / animDuration));

            Log.d("Changing color", "Changing color to RGB" + red + ", " + green + ", " + blue);
            textView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(red, green, blue));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            textView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(endRed, endGreen, endBlue));
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As metioned above, use

```
setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
```

to eliminate the blinking.  The following will fade the textview "tv" from green to red every 30,000 ms without any nervous blinking:

```
public void animateIt(){
    ObjectAnimator a = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(tv, "textColor", Color.GREEN, Color.RED);
    a.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    a.setDuration(30000);
    a.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
    a.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
    a.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
    AnimatorSet t = new AnimatorSet();
    t.play(a);
    t.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I can build on pollaris' answer. Instead of using

```
ObjectAnimator a = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(...)
```

You can instead use,

```
ObjectAnimator a = ObjectAnimator.ofArgb(...)
```