# Photoshop's spot-color channel mixing algorithm

Tags: algorithm, colors, language-agnostic, color-space

Photoshop seems to have a special mode for blending spot-color channels. Let's look at an example: blending full opacity red #ff3c1f with full opacity cyan #1cd4c6.

If I create two spot-color channels with solidity 0% and set their colors to #ff3c1f and #1cd4c6 and fill them with black I get #91550D:

[image: spot color mixing]

Now, I know that combining colors is a complex problem that's not even well-posed ([see related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351442/is-there-an-algorithm-for-color-mixing-that-works-like-mixing-real-colors)). But the result that photoshop gives gets very close to reality most of the time for me. Can anyone help me understand how photoshop does this blending?

I have read on the [Adobe forums](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/928561?start=0&tstart=0) that it's multiplicative blending in CMYK. So I tried to reproduce that with layers, but I am getting #7D4339:

[image: cmyk multiply blending]

I know CMYK is device-dependent but I've tried lots of various profiles but none worked like the spot-color channels. The screenshot is from using the U.S. Web Coated (SWOP) v2 profile.

I tried Multiply blend in Lab and in RGB, but those were even further off.

I would really appreciate any insight on this whatsoever. Thanks!

Comment: It's possible that Adobe has spectrum absorption data for each spot color and combines those directly - it would be very hard to duplicate.

Comment: I don't have Photoshop, so can you do a couple of experiments? First, tell me if the color changes if you reverse the order of the layers. Second, tell me what you get if you make the bottom spot color pure white and pure black.

Comment: @MarkRansom with solidity set to 0% for each channel, the result does not depend on the order of the channels. For bottom black and top anything, I get black; for bottom white and top anything, I get whatever's on top. It does look like multiplicative blending.

Comment: Another test: what do you get when both layers have the same spot color?

Comment: @MarkRansom the result is different. In the case of mixing two pure reds #ff0000, I get #C1000A (rgb[193, 0, 10]). Two yellows #ffff00 produce #E2FF00 (rgb[226, 255, 0]).

Comment: OK, that tells me definitively that they're not using RGB color space. I don't know how to figure this out at this point, sorry.

Comment: Sorry to see that there is no answer. I am also interested in the answer for this. (I am making some javascript code which tried to simulate overprinting pantone colors). Did you ever find out?