# A formula to work out the outcome of a color when applying "css opacity"?

Tags: css, colors, background-color

Let's suppose I apply a CSS opacity rule on some HTML element

```
opacity: .5;
```

is there a formula that helps me figure out how a color will change ?

For instance I'd guess that in my example a div background color of white #FFFFFF
would become #808080

but peraphs I am wrong ?

Comment: Surely this would depend on whatever color is displayed behind your div?

Comment: Are you assuming that it's black underneath everything?

Comment: @thirtydot Yes, I am assuming that it's either all black or all white.

Comment: @Curt if you have a red div and you apply opacity of 0.5 the question becomes: what is going to be the red div ? surely no longer FF0000 so what number ? thanks

Comment: This is a tricky one and it all depends what you want to do, but there is a way but it is a bucket load of algebra. I would suggest looking at rgba which might solve some off your problems as it includes the alpha transparency in it.

Comment: Almost a duplicate of [Convert RGBA color to RGB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049230/convert-rgba-color-to-rgb) except this question 1) uses hex color notation and 2) talks about `opacity` on a solid background color rather than an `rgba()` color. The formula is still applicable, though.

Comment: This won't take you all the way, but it might help a little bit. http://codepen.io/AntonNiklasson/pen/bfDtl

Answer (score 0):

If you have a color picker utility, you could try this type of thing with multiple color arrangements, and then use the color picker to see what they come out to be, and see if you can find any relations.

-Brian