# computing RGBA to match an RGB color

Tags: colors

If I have an RGB color, with 100% opacity.

I want that same color (or close to it) with a transparent alpha channel.  I will paint the transparent color over a white background.

How do I compute the RGBA color?

I guess what I am asking is the [opposite of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049230/convert-rgba-color-to-rgb).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean you want the RGBA color with maximum transparency which, when drawn on top of a white background, gives the original RGB color?

Let *R*<sub>0</sub>, *G*<sub>0</sub> and *B*<sub>0</sub> be the components of the original color, each ranging from 0.0 to 1.0, and let *R*, *G*, *B* and *A* be the components of the new RGBA color (with *A* = 1 denoting 100% opacity).  We know that the colors must satisfy:

> *R*<sub>0</sub> = *A*·*R* + (1 − *A*)
>   *G*<sub>0</sub> = *A*·*G* + (1 − *A*)
>   *B*<sub>0</sub> = *A*·*B* + (1 − *A*)

which, if we knew *A*, we could easily solve for *R*, *G* and *B*:

> *R* = (*R*<sub>0</sub> − 1 + *A*) / *A* = 1 − (1 − *R*<sub>0</sub>) / *A*
>   *G* = (*G*<sub>0</sub> − 1 + *A*) / *A* = 1 − (1 − *G*<sub>0</sub>) / *A*
>   *B* = (*B*<sub>0</sub> − 1 + *A*) / *A* = 1 − (1 − *B*<sub>0</sub>) / *A*

Since we require that *R* ≥ 0, *G* ≥ 0 and *B* ≥ 0, it follows that 1 − *R*<sub>0</sub> ≥ A, 1 − *G*<sub>0</sub> ≥ A and 1 − *B*<sub>0</sub> ≥ A,  and therefore the smallest possible value for *A* is:

> *A* = max( 1 − *R*<sub>0</sub>, 1 − *G*<sub>0</sub>, 1 − *B*<sub>0</sub> ) = 1 − min( *R*<sub>0</sub>, *G*<sub>0</sub>, *B*<sub>0</sub> )

Thus, the color we want is:

> *A* = 1 − min( *R*<sub>0</sub>, *G*<sub>0</sub>, *B*<sub>0</sub> )
>   *R* = 1 − (1 − *R*<sub>0</sub>) / *A*
>   *G* = 1 − (1 − *G*<sub>0</sub>) / *A*
>   *B* = 1 − (1 − *B*<sub>0</sub>) / *A*

---

Ps. For a *black* background, the same formulas would be even simpler:

> *A* = max( *R*<sub>0</sub>, *G*<sub>0</sub>, *B*<sub>0</sub> )
>   *R* = *R*<sub>0</sub> / *A*
>   *G* = *G*<sub>0</sub> / *A*
>   *B* = *B*<sub>0</sub> / *A*

---

Pps. Just to clarify, all the formulas above are for *non*-premultiplied RGBA colors.  For premultiplied alpha, just multiply *R*, *G* and *B* as calculated above by *A*, giving:

> *R* = *A* · ( 1 − (1 − *R*<sub>0</sub>) / *A* ) = *R*<sub>0</sub> − (1 − *A*)
>   *G* = *A* · ( 1 − (1 − *G*<sub>0</sub>) / *A* ) = *G*<sub>0</sub> − (1 − *A*)
>   *B* = *A* · ( 1 − (1 − *B*<sub>0</sub>) / *A* ) = *B*<sub>0</sub> − (1 − *A*)

(or, for a black background, simply *R* = *R*<sub>0</sub>, *G* = *G*<sub>0</sub> and *B* = *B*<sub>0</sub>.)

Comment: Thank you!  So this solves for max alpha... Is there a formula  for min alpha (and, Pushing my luck, the range between)?

Comment: @jedierikb: Um... The alpha value given above _is_ the minimum.  The maximum is _A_ = 1, with _R_ = _R0_, _G_ = _G0_ and _B_ = _B0_.  (And yes, you can interpolate between those: just pick any valid alpha value and use the formulas above to get _R_, _G_ and _B_.)