# Find hexa color created by an rgba color

Tags: javascript, html, css, hex, rgba

I'm looking for a service that help me to find the final hexadecimal value of an rgba color.
For example I have my body background-color set to `#FF0000`.
I have my header positioned over the `<body>` with a background-color set to `rgba(0,0,0,.7)`.
Now, I want to know what is the hexadecimal value of this color mix.

Any ideas ?

Thank you.

Comment: It's right I could use something like photoshop by printing screen and analyse the color code with a tools. but that's not the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746899/how-to-calculate-an-rgb-colour-by-specifying-an-alpha-blending-amount

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063530/computing-rgba-to-match-an-rgb-color

Answer (score 1):

If you use SASS you could even preprocess your CSS and let it calculate the values.
http://jackiebalzer.com/color

I used #FF000 as base color and darkened 70%.

Here is a code pen I just did with SASS:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ozlHD

It returns the hex value of the div which is #4C0000 which is the correct value.

Comment: the red was only an example I couldn't give the real hexa code (ask my boss for that...) but Thanks you ;)

Comment: Does not matter it will work for any color. CSS preprocessing like SASS, LESS is worth the time and investment.

Comment: Ok so this is not exactly what I expected it doesn't take care about opacity..
It gives the same hexa code for any opacity value...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3nkFj/12/ when color picking with ie. colorzilla in firefox gives #4C0000!