# Matplotlib issue when saving imshow as pdf with interpolation and alpha

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting an image with matplotlib, by far the best interpolation parameter for `imshow` in my case is `interpolation='None'` but if I also give an `alpha` parameter, when saving the figure, the alpha is not kept.

Minimal example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

arr = np.abs(np.sin(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi)))
x,y = np.meshgrid(arr,arr)
arr = x*y
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(arr,alpha=arr,interpolation='None')
plt.savefig("fig1.pdf")
```

expected result:

[image]

what I get:

[image]

I only experience this issue for this particular interpolation setting.

matplotlib version: 3.4.3

Answer (score 2):

@mapf suggestion to rasterize is good, but you can just rasterize the image, and not the whole axes; that keeps the axes labels etc as vectors.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

arr = np.abs(np.sin(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi)))
x,y = np.meshgrid(arr, arr)
arr = x*y
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(arr, alpha=arr, interpolation='none', rasterized=True)
fig.savefig("fig1.pdf")
```

[image]

If you really want the image to be vectorized, then save as pcolormesh:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolormesh(arr, alpha=arr)
fig.savefig("fig2.pdf")
```

[image]

If you want imshow's vertical orientation and aspect ratio:

```py
ax.flipud()
ax.set_aspect(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though pdf supports transparency ([unlike eps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19638773/5472354)), if you use [`interpolation='None'`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/interpolation_methods.html), you need to [force a rasterized (bitmap) drawing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64052299/5472354), by using [`ax.set_rasterized(True)`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_rasterized.html):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

arr = np.abs(np.sin(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi)))
x,y = np.meshgrid(arr, arr)
arr = x*y

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.imshow(arr, alpha=arr, interpolation='None')
ax.set_rasterized(True)

fig.savefig("fig1.pdf")
```

Note that by doing this, you are **no longer saving a vector graphic** (and unfortunately loose all the benefits that come with it). Instead, you essentially generate a png that is then incorporated into a pdf. Thus to avoid pixelation, you will probably need to up the dpi.

---

Nevertheless, the easiest solution would probably be to just drop `interpolation='None'`, unless you really need it.

Since you said that `interpolation='None'` works best for your project, but for every other backend [except Agg, ps, pdf and svg](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html#matplotlib-pyplot-imshow) the interpolation defaults to `'nearest'`, what likely *actually* works best for your project is `interpolation='nearest'`. So I would recommend to try that instead.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, it does indeed work but I attach a lot of importance to the output still being vectorially drawn ( otherwise saving as a high quality raster was always a solution). I think I will implement my own alpha method to modify the image and drop the `alpha` parameter in imshow.

Comment: @matmoa  Well the problem lies with `interpolation='None'`. A much simpler way would just be to drop that statement.

Comment: @matmoa see my new edit about trying `interpolation='nearest'`.