# Line Alpha Not Saving Properly in Matplotlib

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, png, alpha

I'm having a baffling issue with saving figures with a specified line alpha in matplotlib. I would really appreciate any input. I found [this previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19638773/matplotlib-plots-lose-transparency-when-saving-as-ps-eps) but changing the rasterization does **not** seem to fix the issue.

Here's the minimal example I have of where this issue shows up:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arr = np.random.randn(10000, 2)
plt.plot(arr[:,0], arr[:,1],alpha=.09, color='black')
plt.savefig('dots_vector.pdf')
plt.show()
```

In the the display window, it looks like the following  (what I want):

[image: desired figure]

However, when I save it as a PDF or PNG, it looks like the following:

[image: sad, incorrect figure]

Note, I've tried the following setting:

```
ax.set_rasterized(True)
```

As that's what the previous thread suggested, but this does **not** fix the problem.

Bizarrely, when I change the marker type of the line, to the following:

```
plt.plot(arr[:,0], arr[:,1], 'o', alpha=.09, color='black')
```

The alpha seems to behave exactly as expected either as a PDF or a PNG, seen here:

[image: Working figure with dots]

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated on how to get the alpha to save properly for the line plot, as I'm pretty stumped.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having exactly the same issue.

Comment: [Here was the best response I could find.](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/477rch/line_alpha_not_saving_properly_in_matplotlib/d0ayti1) It seems like this is a limitation of matplotlib?

Comment: My problem (with python 3.6.1, matplotlib 3.0.0, run from IDLE under Windows 7) is even worse: Your minimal example looks like your 2nd figure even in the display window. It works with markers.