# Converting my image to 'eps'

Tags: image, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, eps

I am using ipython notebook to output my image, I want to output an image whose layout is "eps".Like this:
[image]

My origin image is this:
[image]

But after I saved my "eps" image, I used EPS Viewer to open this file,there are some problems in my image:
[image]

The number of point is less than before.What is the problem?

Comment: Could it be related to transparency and eps as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19638773/matplotlib-plots-lose-transparency-when-saving-as-ps-eps ?