# Non transparent regression line when saving to eps

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, eps

When I generate an `lmplot` in Seaborn in Jupyter lab environment, it shows me the following plot:

[image]

However, by saving the plot as an eps file using `plt.savefig("test.eps")` command, and loading it in a LaTeX document, this image is displayed in which the regression lines are not transparent anymore.
How can I fix this to get the exact same output as the one rendered in the Jupyter environment earlier?

[image]

P.S. I should also mention that, before rendering the image, Jupyter shows me a warning type message saying `The PostScript backend does not support transparency; partially transparent artists will be rendered opaque.`

Comment: probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19638773/matplotlib-plots-lose-transparency-when-saving-as-ps-eps - short answer it seems is: use PDF instead of EPS when creating vector graphics with transparency for latex.

Comment: As @cel said the postscript spec does not allow alpha (transparency) to be saved.