# Displaying an Image Type Double in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have an image typed double in Matlab. How can I `imshow` it? Thanks.

```
load('file.mat');
b=d.l{2,1}.a{1,1}; %//b is an image <96x96x4 double>
imshow(b);
```

Comment: `imshow` doesn't support showing 4 channel images.  What is this image supposed to represent?

Comment: if your image is `NxMx3`, and you made a typo in the comment, use `imshow(b,[])` to autoadjust the limits of the `imshow` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @rayryeng suggests, `imshow` does not like 4 channel images. Thus:

If your image is `NxMx3`, and you made a typo in the comment, use `imshow(b,[])` to auto-adjust the limits of the `imshow` function.

If your 4th channel is alpha, then either ignore the alpha: `imshow(b(:,:,1:3),[])`

Or, convert your image from RGBA to the closest representation in RGB. You can do that with something called [alpha blending](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing), and you have a nice answer (in another programming language) in this SO post:  [Convert RGBA color to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049230/convert-rgba-color-to-rgb)

If neither of these is your case, then you may want to give more information.

Comment: Yes, you are right Ander Biguri. It worked when I ignored the alpha channel. Thanks.

Comment: What about If I want to show an image 25x25 double instead of 96x96x4. I tried to use the imshow function, but it didn't work and shows an error as the following:                                                                                         Index exceeds matrix dimensions.                                                                                       Thanks

Comment: @Dani the size of the image does not have absoutely no influence in `imshow`, so if it didnt work, there is another reason.