# Display a color with transparency? Python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I've currently got a tk.Button used as a color display:

[image]

I have two questions:

1. Is there a better method of simply displaying a color?
2. Is there any way that I can control the displayed transparency of that color?

Answer (score 0):

Display a color with transparency (see this)

[calculate RGB equivalent of base colors with alpha of 0.5 over white background in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33371939/calculate-rgb-equivalent-of-base-colors-with-alpha-of-0-5-over-white-background)

Comment: The convention for showing transparency is not with a white background, but with a checkerboard.