# Plotting confidence intervals in matplotlib WITHOUT alpha

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot in Python using `matplotlib` two curves and some confidence intervals. I do so as follows:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Generate fake data.
rng = np.random.default_rng(0)
y1 = np.cumsum(rng.uniform(0, 1, 10))
y2 = np.cumsum(rng.uniform(0, 1.5, 10))

# Plot the fake data and the fake confidence intervals.
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(y1)
ax.fill_between(range(len(y1)), y1 - 1, y1 + 1, alpha=0.2)
ax.plot(y2)
ax.fill_between(range(len(y2)), y2 - 1, y2 + 1, alpha=0.2)
plt.show()
```

The result is as follows:

[image: Result of toy example].

This is a toy example, I am aware that these confidence intervals do not make any sense mathematically.

**My problem:** I need to save the figure as an EPS (I *cannot* use another format), but `fill_between` uses `alpha=0.2`, and EPS format does not support transparency. Is there any way I can generate the same plot without using transparency?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib Plots Lose Transparency When Saving as .ps/.eps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19638773/matplotlib-plots-lose-transparency-when-saving-as-ps-eps)

Comment: The ideal option seems to use colors that resemble those using `alpha=0.2`. However, there is a problem when different regions overlap. Also, I don't want to use `ax.set_rasterized(True)` because it loses the whole purpose of EPS...

Comment: And saving in pdf is not a viable option for you? Because that would be a vectorized image, but it would support the transparency

Comment: Very sadly, it is not. I prefer pdf format, but some journals require you to submit your figures in EPS format.

Comment: That's really unfortunate, hope you manage something out

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't use transparency, what about using an outline?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
l1 = ax.plot(y1)
ax.plot(y1 - 1, ls=':', c=l1[0].get_color())
ax.plot(y1 + 1, ls=':', c=l1[0].get_color())

l2 = ax.plot(y2)
ax.plot(y2 - 1, ls=':', c=l2[0].get_color())
ax.plot(y2 + 1, ls=':', c=l2[0].get_color())
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I don't have 2, but possibly more curves on each plot, and each curve already uses a different line style ...

Answer (score 2):

**Note**: the answer given below is not a complete solution - it works well for the data given in the question, where there is an overlap between the confidence intervals across the whole x-axis range, *but* it will **not** work (in its current form) if the confidence intervals diverge and do not fully overlap.

You can split the data into the upper band, overlap band, and lower bands and plot them separately using pure RGB colours calculated with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33375738/1862861). E.g.,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from matplotlib.colors import to_rgb

def make_rgb_transparent(rgb, bg_rgb, alpha):
    return [alpha * c1 + (1 - alpha) * c2
            for (c1, c2) in zip(rgb, bg_rgb)]

# Generate fake data.
rng = np.random.default_rng(0)
y1 = np.cumsum(rng.uniform(0, 1, 10))
y2 = np.cumsum(rng.uniform(0, 1.5, 10))

# Plot the fake data and the fake confidence intervals.
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

upper = np.max([y1 + 1, y2 + 1], axis=0)
midupper = np.min([y1 + 1, y2 + 1], axis=0)
midlower = np.max([y1 - 1, y2 - 1], axis=0)
lower = np.min([y1 - 1, y2 - 1], axis=0)

# get colours and equivalent RGBs to alpha
alpha = 0.2
colorupper = "C0"
coloruppertransp = make_rgb_transparent(to_rgb(colorupper), [1, 1, 1], alpha)
colorlower = "C1"
colorlowertransp = make_rgb_transparent(to_rgb(colorlower), [1, 1, 1], alpha)

blended = make_rgb_transparent(colorlowertransp, coloruppertransp, 0.5)

# plot bands
ax.fill_between(range(len(y1)), midupper, upper, color=coloruppertransp)
ax.fill_between(range(len(y1)), midlower, midupper, color=blended)
ax.fill_between(range(len(y1)), lower, midlower, color=colorlowertransp)

# plot lines on top
ax.plot(y1, color=colorlower)
ax.plot(y2, color=colorupper)

plt.show()
```

gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is a great solution. I forgot to precise however that I don't have 2 curves but an unknown number, which would immensely complicate the code... Since even MATLAB can do this under the hood, I thought there were a simpler way using Matplotlib

Answer (score 1):

Here I use the colours from [Matt's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77899812/3501128), but use shapely to work out and plot where the bands overlap.  I also reduced the confidence intervals to +/- 0.9 so we can see a gap where they do not overlap.

```
# Plot the fake data and the fake confidence intervals.
import shapely.geometry as sgeom
import shapely.plotting as splot

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(y1)
poly1 = ax.fill_between(range(len(y1)), y1 - 0.9, y1 + 0.9, color=coloruppertransp)
ax.plot(y2)
poly2 = ax.fill_between(range(len(y2)), y2 - 0.9, y2 + 0.9, color=colorlowertransp)

# Convert Matplotlib polygons to shapely polygons.
spoly1 = sgeom.Polygon(poly1.get_paths()[0].vertices)
spoly2 = sgeom.Polygon(poly2.get_paths()[0].vertices)

# Find and plot the intersection.
spoly_intersection = spoly1.intersection(spoly2)
splot.plot_polygon(spoly_intersection, add_points=False, color=blended,
                   edgecolor=blended, alpha=1)
```

[image]

Edit: I guess shapely added the gridlines and fixed aspect ratio, which we can turn off again with

```
ax.set_aspect('auto')
ax.grid(visible=False)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a really clean solution, though hard to general to more than 2 curves