# How to correctly blend two or more colors?

Tags: c#, .net, colors, xna

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Algorithm for Additive Color Mixing for RGB Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726549/algorithm-for-additive-color-mixing-for-rgb-values)

I'm working on a light system for my game and I almost completed it.
But I have one question inherent to colors: How do I blend them properly?

The simplest answer I found and used was to average their RGB values, but there's the problem of results tending toward grey when they get averaged many times.
To explain it briefly, the method I used was the following:

```
// XNA, where there isn't a FromARGB method, and the 
// values are given in the constructor.    
Color result = new Color(
    (C1.R + C2.R) / 2, 
    (C1.G + C2.G) / 2, 
    (C1.B + C2.B) / 2
);
```

But if I have to blend many different colors while retaining the most correct value, what should I do? I opened a new question because I don't know much about colors, and am not sure if different circumstances (ex. lights) need different methods.
Thanks in advance for the replies.