# Mixing text colors in HTML

Tags: html

Using HTML, is there any way to mix text colors according to the tags that each selection of text is inside of? This pseudocode describes the type of text color mixture that I'm trying to create:

```
<red>
    This text should be red.
    <blue>
        This text should be purple, since it is inside red and blue tags.
    </blue>
    This text should be red.
    <white>
        This text should be pink, since it is inside white and red tags.
    </white>
</red>
```

Is it possible to convert this pseudocode to valid HTML, so that the text colors are combined in this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dynamically, not [without scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726549/algorithm-for-additive-color-mixing-for-rgb-values). You can, however, define some CSS rules.

```
.red {
    color: red;
}
    .red .white,
    .white .red {
        color: pink;
    }
    .red .blue,
    .blue .red {
        color: purple;
    }
.blue {
    color: blue;
}
    .blue .white 
    .white .blue {
        color: light-blue;
    }
```

etc.

This can be as simple or as complicated as you need.

**EDIT:** Here's the jsfiddle for demonstration purposes: http://jsfiddle.net/LhSk2/

Comment: This solves my problem. :) Is it also possible to do this using transparent image backgrounds (so that the images are mixed according to the surrounding tags?)

Comment: You would need semi transparent PNG images and place them as backgrounds.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to support IE8 and below, you can use semi transparent RGBA colors:

```
<div style="background: red">
    This text should be red.
    <div style="background: rgba(128, 0, 128, .5)">
        This text should be purple, since it is inside red and blue tags.
    </div>
    This text should be red.
    <div style="background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5)">
        This text should be pink, since it is inside white and red tags.
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zT8JD/

Comment: @AndersonGreen - This only works with background colors. If you want to do this with the text color, you'll have to specify the actual colors.

Comment: Why doesn't it work with the text colors as well as the background colors?

Comment: @AndersonGreen - Because the local declarations will always override the parent declarations. When using semi-transparent background colors, the parent's background color will leak through the transparency.

Comment: Here's a slightly more complicated example: http://jsfiddle.net/jarble/zT8JD/1/ The effect is very visually interesting, I think. :)

Comment: Just out of curiosity: would it be possible to do this using transparent image backgrounds as well as color backgrounds?

Comment: @AndersonGreen - You can have your image backgrounds be semi-transparent themselves.

Comment: How would semi-transparent image backgrounds be declared, then? :D

Comment: @AndersonGreen - The image itself would have to be semi-transparent.