# tinted overlay - negate tint effect for a specific element

Tags: android-layout, colors

I have a layout that is covered entirely by a tint overlay (it's the last element in my RelativeLayout).

1. I have `TextView1` and `TextView2` with `textColor` set to red (`#FF0000`).
2. My tint overlay is grey with transparency set - `#88676767`.
3. I want my `TextView1` tinted but `TextView2` appear red (`#FF0000`).

Is there a way for me to calculate color value `X` for `TextView2` so when it is overlayed with a tint layer it appears to the user as red (`#FF0000`)? If so, how do I go about calculating this value?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to achieve this. The color is calculated as

`(color1.R*color1.A + color2.R*color2.A)/(color1.A+color2.A)`

This equation does not have solution for `color1.R in (0, 255)` and `color1.A in (0, 1)` when `color2` is your overlay and result color is 255.

Find more info in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/727339/4584675).