# How to blend two RGB colors (front and back) based on their alpha channels

Tags: python, alpha, rgba

I'm trying to combine two RGBA colors, given in tuples, like (0, 0, 0, 128) and (255, 255, 255, 128). I've already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726549/algorithm-for-additive-color-mixing-for-rgb-values#51835382) which was quite helpful, but my current code (Python)

```
def get_color(colorRGBA1, colorRGBA2):
    alpha = 255 - (255 - colorRGBA1[3]) * (255 - colorRGBA2[3])
    red   = (colorRGBA1[0] * (255 - colorRGBA2[3]) + colorRGBA2[0] * colorRGBA2[3]) / 255
    green = (colorRGBA1[1] * (255 - colorRGBA2[3]) + colorRGBA2[1] * colorRGBA2[3]) / 255
    blue  = (colorRGBA1[2] * (255 - colorRGBA2[3]) + colorRGBA2[2] * colorRGBA2[3]) / 255
    return (int(red), int(green), int(blue), int(alpha))
```

somehow returns some weird numbers (like -15874) as alpha. Everything else works fine, but I can't figure out how to get the new color's alpha value.

Both colors will have alpha values ranging from 0 to 255.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct code is:

```
def get_color(colorRGBA1, colorRGBA2):
    alpha = 255 - ((255 - colorRGBA1[3]) * (255 - colorRGBA2[3]) / 255)
    red   = (colorRGBA1[0] * (255 - colorRGBA2[3]) + colorRGBA2[0] * colorRGBA2[3]) / 255
    green = (colorRGBA1[1] * (255 - colorRGBA2[3]) + colorRGBA2[1] * colorRGBA2[3]) / 255
    blue  = (colorRGBA1[2] * (255 - colorRGBA2[3]) + colorRGBA2[2] * colorRGBA2[3]) / 255
    return (int(red), int(green), int(blue), int(alpha))
```

...because I have to divide `(255 - colorRGBA1[3]) * (255 - colorRGBA2[3])` by `255` to get a valid alpha value.

Answer (score 1):

See solution in JavaScript at https://gist.github.com/JordanDelcros/518396da1c13f75ee057

Please note that this implementation has **alpha** in [0,1] range, so divide your alpha values by 255 before mixing and at the end multiply the final alpha by 255.