# Algorithm to find which two colors mix to form a third color (in JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, colors, color-theory

I am looking for a library/algorithm/technique to take the 3 additive or subtractive colors and determine what [combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_mixing) of two results in some color `x`.

This is not a correct example (as I don't know much about color theory yet), but this is to illustrate the point. Say you have a color like greenish brown `#45512b`. The problem to solve is figure out -- for the two systems (additive and subtractive) -- the pair of colors that will generate greenish brown (the given color).

So you have the value "greenish brown" `#45512b`, and want to know what paints mix together to form this color. Maybe it is `#fff123` and `#bbb456` that combine subtractively to form greenish brown (just making this up). Then for additive mixing, figuring out the two shades of light of the 3 base colors of light used in computational models that combine to form greenish brown.

Basically just looking for this:

```
function additiveComponents(color) {
  return [ a, b ]
}

function subtractiveComponents(color) {
  return [ a, b ]
}
```

The input color doesn't need to be in hex format, any of the [color spaces](https://github.com/colorjs/color-space) would work. But in the end I would like to convert the two output values back to a hex value.

One naive way I could imagine doing this is to take the [reverse algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726549/algorithm-for-additive-color-mixing-for-rgb-values) (algorithm to mix two colors into a third color), and try every combination of colors until you find the right one. But that would be super inefficient, wondering if there is a better way or standard technique.

Comment: Am I missing something, but are there not a multitude of colors that will add to create a single color?

Comment: In any case - does [xolor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xolor) work for you?

Comment: I have no idea lol, but I could see that.

Comment: Nice! It has this: "
xolorObject.add(otherColor) - Returns the additive mix of the two colors.
xolorObject.subtractive(otherColor) - Returns the subtractive mix of the two colors." However, still the same problem, how to do the _reverse_ of that operation.

Comment: Alas, it doesn't have the functionality I'm looking for :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use **RGB color model**. I am assuming you got 8 bit per channel color `c0=(r0,g0,b0)` and want to know `c1,c2` that mix back to `c0`.

**Additive mixing (light sources)**

1. **chose one color `c1`**

   to be able to mix up to `c0` the `c1` must be less or equal to `c0` on per channel bases. So for example random lesser color:

   ```
   r1 = Random(r0);
   g1 = Random(g0);
   b1 = Random(b0);
   ```
2. **compute the missing color `c2`**

   simply use the additive logic:

   ```
   c0 = c1 + c2
   ```

   so

   ```
   c2 = c0 - c1

   r2 = r0 - r1
   g2 = g0 - g1
   b2 = b0 - b1
   ```

**Substractive mixing (filters, paint colors)**

1. **chose one color `c1`**

   this time `c1` must be `c1>=c0` so again random such color example:

   ```
   r1 = r0 + Random(255-r0);
   g1 = g0 + Random(255-g0);
   b1 = b0 + Random(255-b0);
   ```
2. **compute the missing color `c2`**

   simply use the substractive logic:

   ```
   c0 = c1 - c2
   ```

   so

   ```
   c2 = c1 - c0

   r2 = r1 - r0
   g2 = g1 - g0
   b2 = b1 - b0
   ```

**[Edit1] example**

I just encoded a simple C++/VCL app to test this. So I got 3 sscrollbars to chose RGB of target color `c0` and then some panels to show the `c1,c2` and their mix to visually verify its working as should. Here the code:

```cpp
//$$---- Form CPP ----
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "win_main.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
const int _r=0; // channel order
const int _g=1;
const int _b=2;
const int _a=3;
union color
    {
    BYTE db[4]; // channel access
    DWORD dd;   // all 32 bit of color
    TColor c;   // VCL/GDI color  (you can ignore this)
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner):TForm(Owner)
    {
    sb_rgbChange(this);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::sb_rgbChange(TObject *Sender)
    {
    int i;
    color c0,c1,c2,c;
    Randomize();
    // get c0 color from R,G,B sliders
    c0.db[_r]=255-sb_r->Position;
    c0.db[_g]=255-sb_g->Position;
    c0.db[_b]=255-sb_b->Position;
    c0.db[_a]=0;
    pan_c0->Color=c0.c;     // just show color on some panel
    // additive
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) c1.db[i]=Random(c0.db[i]);  c1.db[_a]=0;  // generate c1 <= c0
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) c2.db[i]=c0.db[i]-c1.db[i]; c2.db[_a]=0;  // compute c2 = c0 - c1
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)  c.db[i]=c1.db[i]+c2.db[i]; c.db[_a]=0;   // verify  c  = c1 + c2
    pan_add_c1->Color=c1.c; // just show colors on some panels
    pan_add_c2->Color=c2.c;
    pan_add_c ->Color= c.c;
    // substractive
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) c1.db[i]=c0.db[i]+Random(255-c0.db[i]); c1.db[_a]=0;  // generate c1 >= c0
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) c2.db[i]=c1.db[i]-c0.db[i];             c2.db[_a]=0;  // compute c2 = c1 - c0
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)  c.db[i]=c1.db[i]-c2.db[i];              c.db[_a]=0;  // verify  c  = c1 - c2
    pan_sub_c1->Color=c1.c; // just show colors on some panels
    pan_sub_c2->Color=c2.c;
    pan_sub_c ->Color= c.c;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And here a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

The only important stuff in code is the  `sb_rgbChange` event which is called on any change of any of the 3 scrollbars. It compute the `c1,c2` colors for both additive and substractive logic and output the colors into pannels.

It works without any problem... btw You where right even my `Random(x)` generates `x` so the limit should be 255 (I already repaired the answer).

Here complete source code (**BDS2006 C++/VCL/Win32**) and Win32 binary:

- [Demo](https://ulozto.net/!EJbD5jvFSsHA/color-mixer2-zip)

Comment: Holy cow I did not think this was going to be possible! Going to take me a little while to digest this! Thank you.

Comment: Wondering if you could explain at a higher level how this works :). So this is saying that you can mix any two colors and it will form the third color?

Comment: @LancePollard its simple linear equation ... `A + B = C` or `A - B = C` with the notion that `A,B,C` can not be negative that is why you need to select `A` as lower or bigger color than the target one `C`. Appart of that you can chose any A and compute B so they combine to C.

Comment: Wondering if I got it right: https://jsfiddle.net/oh3bpcgw/1/. Mainly wondering if using 255 is the correct choice instead of 256.

Comment: Also wondering if I could say, "Okay, I want to figure out what 2 colors generate x, and I want one of the components/colors to be this specific blue, so the other must be y", or if there is only a subset of colors from which I can choose (i.e. the `startingWith` value).

Comment: Also have the question, of how many color pairs there are that can mix into the third color, if it's just a few, or thousands, or millions even.

Comment: @LancePollard on integer you are limited by the possible counts to sum up to given colors (you know if you got 8bit per channel then there are only 256^3 of possible colors to chose from and due to the < or > constraint you can use only part of them ... the closer to White/Black the less colors to chose from...)  but on floats you're virtually without limit until hitting the precision barrier of coarse.

Comment: @LancePollard 255/256 depends on the Random implementation. The one I got in my C++ environment `Random(X)` is generating numbers `<0,X-1>` and never `X` hence `256` but if yours generate `<0,X>` then 255 is correct ... look in the documentation to your environment to clarify which one it is ... or simply generate and print 100 times `Random(5)` and look if it generated 5 or not ....

Comment: Can you please check my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oh3bpcgw/1/), I am getting incorrect mixing results when I try this now.

Comment: @LancePollard See edit 1 so you got something to compare to ... I use no floats in there just integer math ... My bet is you are mixing float and integer math in a wrong way. Sadly I do not code in JAVASCRIPT so i can not debug but I would expect some entry point or events in the code or at least hard coded  test case and some output but I see none of that in your code ...