# get real background color with opacity

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```js
console.log($("#box4").css("background-color")); // Solution does not fit
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box1" style="background-color: blue; opacity: 0.5;">
  <div id="box2" style="background-color: yellow; opacity: 0.5;">
    <div id="box3" style="bacground-color: green; opacity: 0.5;">
      <div id="box4" style="font-size: 30px; padding: 20px; opacity: 0.9;">Aloha</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Need to get background-color value for **id="box4"** with JS oder JQ.
The **real** value of the color that the user sees in the browser must be found. **Not a CSS value.**

You need to either calculate the color change with an opacity value, or some other solution.

If I use the "COLOR PICKER" google chrome plugin, I get the value #a0b0c0, rgb(160, 176, 192).

It is enough if the speech will only work in google chrome.

Comment: Will asking for the `css` value work?  `console.log ( $('#box4').css("opacity") );
console.log ( $('#box4').css("background-color") );`

Comment: And .. As `#box4` contains no `background` property .. It will return undefined or null ...  Are you trying to get the background color of a div that's BEHIND `#box4` ?

Comment: The real value of the color that the user sees in the browser must be found. Not a CSS value.

Comment: This is as close as you will get to what you are wanting to do .. https://pqina.nl/blog/use-the-javascript-eye-dropper-api-to-select-colors-on-the-web/   You may be able to create some JS to manipulate it by placing the cursor where you want and generating an artificial "click" ..

Comment: Now that's interesting, I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: There's a lot of discussion on algorithms here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726549/algorithm-for-additive-color-mixing-for-rgb-values but I cannot find a definitive statement of what would be used by any one system. Hope someone knows.