ChartJS : Fill within a curve dataset above a max, in between max/min, and below min limit with different color
Rails 5, ChartKick 5.0.5 => ChartJS 4.4.1
I have a curved line chart in ChartJS that plots about 0 on the Y axis with separate maximum threshold for positive values and minimum for negative values (both linear). I am trying to fill within the curve above and below the thresholds with one color, and between the thresholds with a different color, within the curve.
I have tried a few different ways of applying fill to multiple datasets to achive the result I'm trying to get after.
1: I broke the curve dataset into three different datasets. Over max threshold, below max threshold, and between.  I got close, but I could not figure out how to get the fill to work inside the curve between the min/max when the curve was outside of the thresholds. Also, the tooltip was showing the broken up curve as three separate lines colors.
2 (Code below, pic of result): I tried a single curve dataset while overlaying above and below fill. And while this does work, the color pallet does not jive with the rest of my application and other charts.
>! Ruby, using ChartKick interface

def chart_datasets
      @chart_datasets ||=
        [
          {
            name: station_name,
            data: generate_chart_data(&:speed),
            dataset: {
              fill: {
                target: 'origin',
                below: 'rgba(0,204,102, 0.2)',
                above: 'rgba(0,204,102, 0.2)'
              }
            }
          },
          {
            name: 'Max',
            data: generate_chart_data(max_limit),
            dataset: {
              fill: {
                target: 0,
                below: 'rgba(220,53,69, 0.6)',
                above: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)'

              }
            }
          },
          {
            name: 'Min',
            data: generate_chart_data(min_limit),
            dataset: {
              fill: {
                target: 0,
                above: 'rgba(220,53,69, 0.6)',
                below: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)'
              }
            }
          }
        ]
    end

Results of #2 - Note I have removed a third threshold at 0 from the code above, but this is the result. I need the brown areas to be red :)

I tried CoPilot, who mentioned theres a 'between' property on the fill object in ChartJS, but I couldn't find any documentation on that property, and it's example code never worked.


If javascript code in the chart.js configuration object passes through your framework, you can create a
gradient for the
backgroundColor that would work without any need to set fills for other datasets or other complications, see this snippet:


const stopsAt = [-2, 2];
const config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: Array.from({length: 100}, (_, i)=>new Date(Date.parse('2024-05-25') + 3 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 * i /100)),
        datasets:[
            {
                data: Array.from({length: 100}, (_, i)=>Math.sin(i/5)*(1+0.45*Math.sin(i/40+2))*3),
                fill: true,
                backgroundColor: function(context){
                    const yAxis = context.chart.scales.y;
                    if(!yAxis.max){
                        return 'rgba(0,0,0,0)';
                    }
                    const ygStops = [yAxis.min, ...stopsAt, yAxis.max].map(yAxis.getPixelForValue, yAxis);
                    const fractions = ygStops.map(y =>
                        (y-ygStops[0])/(ygStops[ygStops.length-1]-ygStops[0])
                    );
                    const gradientFill = context.chart.ctx.createLinearGradient(0, ygStops[0], 0, ygStops[ygStops.length-1]);
                    gradientFill.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(220, 53, 69, 0.5)');
                    gradientFill.addColorStop(fractions[1], 'rgba(220, 53, 69, 0.5)');
                    gradientFill.addColorStop(fractions[1], 'rgba(0, 204, 102, 0.2)');
                    gradientFill.addColorStop(fractions[2], 'rgba(0, 204, 102, 0.2)');
                    gradientFill.addColorStop(fractions[2], 'rgba(220, 53, 69, 0.6)');
                    gradientFill.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(220, 53, 69, 0.6)');
                    return gradientFill;
                },

                pointRadius: 0,
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            {
                data: Array(100).fill(2),
                borderColor: '#f00',
                pointRadius: 0
            },
            {
                data: Array(100).fill(0),
                borderColor: '#f00',
                borderDash: [10, 7],
                pointRadius: 0
            },
            {
                data: Array(100).fill(-2),
                borderColor: '#f80',
                pointRadius: 0
            }]
    },
    options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
            x: {
                type: 'time',
                time:{
                    unit: 'day'
                }
            },
            y:{
                min: -5,
                max: 5
            }
        },
        plugins:{
            legend:{
                display: false
            }
        }
    },
};

new Chart('myChart', config);
<div style="min-height:70vh">
    <canvas id='myChart'></canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>



Your solution from the code you posted can also be used. The first thing is to reverse the order of the fills,
that means the order in which the colors are applied, since color mixing it is not symmetric. If the background
(first color applied) is the green one with transparency of 0.2, the result will be much closer to the second
red color, than the other way around:


const config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: Array.from({length: 100}, (_, i)=>new Date(Date.parse('2024-05-25') + 3 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 * i /100)),
        datasets:[
            {
                data: Array(100).fill(2), // line at y = 2
                borderColor: '#f00',
                fill: {
                    target: '+2',
                    below: 'rgba(220,53,69,0.6)',
                    above: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)'
                },
                pointRadius: 0
            },
            {
                data: Array(100).fill(-2), // line at y = -2
                borderColor: '#f80',
                pointRadius: 0,
                fill: {
                    target: '+1',
                    above: 'rgba(220,53,69, 0.6)',
                    below: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)'
                },
            },
            {
                data: Array.from({length: 100}, (_, i)=>Math.sin(i/5)*(1+0.45*Math.sin(i/40+2))*3),
                fill: {
                    target: 'origin',
                    below: 'rgba(0,204,102, 0.2)',
                    above: 'rgba(0,204,102, 0.2)'
                },
                pointRadius: 0,
                borderWidth: 0
            },

            {
                data: Array(100).fill(0),
                borderColor: '#f00',
                borderDash: [10, 7],
                pointRadius: 0
            },
        ]
    },
    options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
            x: {
                type: 'time',
                time:{
                    unit: 'day'
                }
            },
            y:{
                min: -5,
                max: 5
            }
        },
        plugins:{
            legend:{
                display: false
            }
        }
    },
};

new Chart('myChart', config);
<div style="min-height:70vh">
    <canvas id='myChart'></canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>



The next step is to replace the fill color rgba(220, 53, 69, 0.6) to another color (colorX, that will be computed) such that the result of combining the green background with this new color is the color you wanted initially. I'll use the following notation, to express it as an equation:
rgba(0, 204, 102, 0.2) ⨁ colorX = rgba(220, 53, 69, 0.6) 

where the color to the left of ⨁ is the background color, or the first color applied, and the color to the right of ⨁ is the foreground or the second color applied. Note for correctness that the actual first color is the
background of the canvas; if it's white, we'll have a rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) ⨁ in front of both terms above, but this simplifies out and doesn't influence the result.
Unfortunately, the equation above has no solution; however, if we increase the alpha of the red color to 0.65, we'll get a solution:
rgba(0, 204, 102, 0.2) ⨁ rgba(254, 30, 64, 0.56) = rgba(220, 53, 69, 0.65)

so, if we replace rgba(220, 53, 69, 0.65) with the newly computed rgba(254, 30, 64, 0.56) we'll get very close to what was
intended:


const config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: Array.from({length: 100}, (_, i)=>new Date(Date.parse('2024-05-25') + 3 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 * i /100)),
        datasets:[
            {
                data: Array(100).fill(2), // line at y = 2
                borderColor: '#f00',
                fill: {
                    target: '+2',
                    below: 'rgba(254,30,64,0.56)',
                    above: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)'
                },
                pointRadius: 0
            },
            {
                data: Array(100).fill(-2), // line at y = -2
                borderColor: '#f80',
                pointRadius: 0,
                fill: {
                    target: '+1',
                    above: 'rgba(254,30,64,0.56)',
                    below: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)'
                },
            },
            {
                data: Array.from({length: 100}, (_, i)=>Math.sin(i/5)*(1+0.45*Math.sin(i/40+2))*3),
                fill: {
                    target: 'origin',
                    below: 'rgba(0,204,102, 0.2)',
                    above: 'rgba(0,204,102, 0.2)'
                },
                pointRadius: 0,
                borderWidth: 0
            },

            {
                data: Array(100).fill(0),
                borderColor: '#f00',
                borderDash: [10, 7],
                pointRadius: 0
            },
        ]
    },
    options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
            x: {
                type: 'time',
                time:{
                    unit: 'day'
                }
            },
            y:{
                min: -5,
                max: 5
            }
        },
        plugins:{
            legend:{
                display: false
            }
        }
    },
};

new Chart('myChart', config);
<div style="min-height:70vh">
    <canvas id='myChart'></canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>



The calculations of the color algebra above can be found in the follwing snippet:


const colBck = 'rgba(0, 204, 102, 0.2)';
const colTarget = 'rgba(220, 53, 69, 0.65)';
// solve colBck ⨁ colX = colTarget
// in colBck ⨁ colX, colBck is the background, the first color applied, colX is the foreground, the second color applied.

const colBckCompArr = parseRgba(colBck),
    colTargetCompArr = parseRgba(colTarget);

try{
    const colXCompArr = invMixRgbaForForeground(colTargetCompArr, colBckCompArr);
    const colX = `rgba(${colXCompArr.join(', ')})`;

    document.querySelector('#formulaLHS').innerText = `${colX} ⨁\n   ${colBck}`;
    document.querySelector('#formulaRHS').innerText = ` \n${colTarget}`;

    const el1 = document.querySelector('#canvas1'),
        ctx1 = el1.getContext("2d");
    ctx1.fillStyle = colBck;  // apply background
    ctx1.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    ctx1.fillStyle = colX;  // then apply color X
    ctx1.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
}
catch(err){
    document.querySelector('#error').innerText = err;
}

const el2 = document.querySelector('#canvas2'),
    ctx2 = el2.getContext("2d");
ctx2.fillStyle = colTarget;
ctx2.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100); // compare to: apply just target color

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// functions used, and some possibly needed for other combinations
function parseRgba(s){
    return s.replace(/rgba\(([^\)]+)\)/, '$1').split(',').map(s => s.trim()).map(parseFloat);
}

// formulae from e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/727339/16466946
function mixRgba([r1, g1, b1, a1], [r2, g2, b2, a2]){ // color1 is background, color2 is foreground
    const ar = a2 + a1 * (1 - a2);
    return [
        Math.round((r2 * a2 + r1 * a1 * (1 - a2)) / ar), // rx * ax = rr * ar - r1 * a1 * (1-ax)
        Math.round((g2 * a2 + g1 * a1 * (1 - a2)) / ar),
        Math.round((b2 * a2 + b1 * a1 * (1 - a2)) / ar),
        Math.round(ar * 100)/100,
    ];
}
function invMixRgbaForForeground([r3, g3, b3, a3], [r1, g1, b1, a1]){
    // find colX from col1 ⨁ colX = col3
    const aX = (a3 - a1)/ (1 - a1);
    const [rX, gX, bX] = [
        Math.round((r3 * a3 - r1 * a1 * (1 - aX)) / aX),
        Math.round((g3 * a3 - g1 * a1 * (1 - aX)) / aX),
        Math.round((b3 * a3 - b1 * a1 * (1 - aX)) / aX)
    ];

    if(rX < 0 || rX > 255 || gX < 0 || gX > 255 || bX < 0 || bX > 255 || aX < 0 || aX > 1){
        throw new Error(`There's no color to produce that mix `+
            `[solution = rgba(${rX}, ${gX}, ${bX}, ${Math.round(aX*100)/100})]`);
    }
    return[rX, gX, bX, Math.round(aX * 100)/100];
}

function invMixRgbaForBackground([r3, g3, b3, a3], [r2, g2, b2, a2]){
    // find colX from colX ⨁ col2 = colTarget
    const aX = (a3 - a2) / (1 - a2);
    const [rX, gX, bX] = [
        Math.round((r3 * a3 - r2 * a2) / (1 - a2) / aX),
        Math.round((g3 * a3 - g2 * a2) / (1 - a2) / aX),
        Math.round((b3 * a3 - b2 * a2) / (1 - a2) / aX)
    ];

    if(rX < 0 || rX > 255 || gX < 0 || gX > 255 || bX < 0 || bX > 255 || aX < 0 || aX > 1){
        throw new Error(`There's no color to produce that mix `+
            `[solution = rgba(${rX}, ${gX}, ${bX}, ${Math.round(aX*100)/100})]`);
    }
    return[rX, gX, bX, Math.round(aX * 100)/100];
}
<div style="display: inline-block;text-align: center; border: 1px dashed #888">
    <canvas id ="canvas1" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
    <div id="formulaLHS" style="font-family: monospace; font-size: smaller"></div>
</div> =
<div style="display: inline-block; text-align: center; border: 1px dashed #888">
    <canvas id ="canvas2" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
    <div id="formulaRHS" style="font-family: monospace; font-size: smaller"></div>
</div>
<div id="error" style="font-family: monospace; color: red"></div>




Many thanks, @kikon!  I am still getting my head wrapped around how option 1 works using gradients.  I feel that is a cleaner option, IMO.  And thank you for option 2. I actually didn't realize color calculations were an option.  Appreciate the assist.
